# Horizontally scroll ALL rows of UICollectionView together

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have `UITableView`. Inside `UITableViewCell` I have placed `UICollectionView`. Currently all the row scrolling individually. What I need is when User scroll any row in horizontally manner (left to right or right to left) all the row must be scroll on same pattern.

I have followed the below link but no success

[Scroll Multiple UICollectionView with one collectionview IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761525/scroll-multiple-uicollectionview-with-one-collectionview-ios)

[Manually scrolling two UICollectionViews showing the same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303772/manually-scrolling-two-uicollectionviews-showing-the-same-content)

Please have look my code

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var categories = ["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", "Header 4", "Header 5", "Header 6", "Header 7", "Header 8"]

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CategoryRow
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CategoryRow(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        }
        else {
        }
        cell!.tag = indexPath.section
        cell?.collection.reloadData()
        return cell!
    }
}
```

**MyCollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var data: UILabel!
}
```

**CategoryRow**

```
import UIKit

class CategoryRow: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var Title1 = ["1st Title 1", "1st Title 2", "1st Title 3", "1st Title 4", "1st Title 5", "1st Title 6", "1st Title 7", "1st Title 8"]
    var Data1 =  ["1st Data 1", "1st Data 2", "1st Data 3", "1st Data 4", "1st Data 5", "1st Data 6", "1st Data 7", "1st Data 8"]

    var Title2 = ["2nd Title 1", "2nd Title 2", "2nd Title 3", "2nd Title 4", "2nd Title 5", "2nd Title 6", "2nd Title 7", "2nd Title 8"]
    var Data2 =  ["2nd Data 1", "2nd Data 2", "2nd Data 3", "2nd Data 4", "2nd Data 5", "2nd Data 6", "2nd Data 7", "2nd Data 8"]

    var Title3 = ["3rd Title 1", "3rd Title 2", "3rd Title 3", "3rd Title 4", "3rd Title 5", "3rd Title 6", "3rd Title 7", "3rd Title 8"]
    var Data3 =  ["3rd Data 1", "3rd Data 2", "3rd Data 3", "3rd Data 4", "3rd Data 5", "3rd Data 6", "3rd Data 7", "3rd Data 8"]

    var Title4 = ["4th Title 1", "4th Title 2", "4th Title 3", "4th Title 4", "4th Title 5", "4th Title 6", "4th Title 7", "4th Title 8"]
    var Data4 =  ["4th Data 1", "4th Data 2", "4th Data 3", "4th Data 4", "4th Data 5", "4th Data 6", "4th Data 7", "4th Data 8"]

    var Title5 = ["5th Title 1", "5th Title 2", "5th Title 3", "5th Title 4", "5th Title 5", "5th Title 6", "5th Title 7", "5th Title 8"]
    var Data5 =  ["5th Data 1", "5th Data 2", "5th Data 3", "5th Data 4", "5th Data 5", "5th Data 6", "5th Data 7", "5th Data 8"]

    var Title6 = ["6th Title 1", "6th Title 2", "6th Title 3", "6th Title 4", "6th Title 5", "6th Title 6", "6th Title 7", "6th Title 8"]
    var Data6 =  ["6th Data 1", "6th Data 2", "6th Data 3", "6th Data 4", "6th Data 5", "6th Data 6", "6th Data 7", "6th Data 8"]

    var Title7 = ["7th Title 1", "7th Title 2", "7th Title 3", "7th Title 4", "7th Title 5", "7th Title 6", "7th Title 7", "7th Title 8"]
    var Data7 =  ["7th Data 1", "7th Data 2", "7th Data 3", "7th Data 4", "7th Data 5", "7th Data 6", "7th Data 7", "7th Data 8"]

    var Title8 = ["8th Title 1", "8th Title 2", "8th Title 3", "8th Title 4", "8th Title 5", "8th Title 6", "8th Title 7", "8th Title 8"]
    var Data8 =  ["8th Data 1", "8th Data 2", "8th Data 3", "8th Data 4", "8th Data 5", "8th Data 6", "8th Data 7", "8th Data 8"]

    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Some logic here
    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        switch (self.tag) {
            case 0:
                cell.title.text = self.Title1[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data1[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 1:
                cell.title.text = self.Title2[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data2[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 2:
                cell.title.text = self.Title3[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data3[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 3:
                cell.title.text = self.Title4[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data4[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 4:
                cell.title.text = self.Title5[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data5[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 5:
                cell.title.text = self.Title6[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data6[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 6:
                cell.title.text = self.Title7[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data7[indexPath.row]
                break

            case 7:
                cell.title.text = self.Title8[indexPath.row]
                cell.data.text = self.Data8[indexPath.row]
                break

            default:
                break
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Edit - 1**

Link for project it may be helpful to understand the scenario

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0drBRiVjY71Tl9vUER6Zk44VFk/view?usp=sharing

**Edit - 2**
I have tried to implement below link but not able to do so

[Synchronized horizontal scrolling of collection views in tableview rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983373/synchronized-horizontal-scrolling-of-collection-views-in-tableview-rows)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the expected behaviour little bit in detail ?

Comment: I think this may be possible by calling the delegate method for scrolling for all other collection views inside the delegate call for the collection view you actually scroll

Comment: Gihan, i have upload the link of project may be it will help you to got the scenario.

Comment: I will check your code and update the answer tonight. Bit busy with work now

Answer (score 3):

Say that you have 2 collection views. What you can do is something like this.

```
// say cv0 and cv1 are outlets to two table views

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.cv0 {
        self.cv1.contentOffset = self.cv0.contentOffset
    }
    else {
        if scrollView == self.tv1 {
            self.cv0.contentOffset = self.cv1.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to it for more collection views you can write a generic method to handle it. You can pass scrollView to this method and all other scroll views in the stack contentOffSet is set accordingly.

Comment: Gihan, Can you please tell me how can I get cv0 and cv1 ?

Comment: You can keep a reference to them in an array. Or you could get all the visible rows from tableView using var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get } and get the cells and then the scrollviews

Comment: i have tried it using this 
var visibleItems = self.collection.indexPathsForVisibleItems()
let currentItem = visibleItems[0]
let nextItem = NSIndexPath(forItem: currentItem.item + 1, inSection: currentItem.section)
self.collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(nextItem, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Right, animated: true)
is it correct ?
any code would be highly appreciates.

Comment: I will look at your code in a moment. bit busy right now.

Comment: @Gihan,I have similar issue. Can you please check it if you can help ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Impossible for help issue resolved now.

First I was set the tag `cell?.collection.tag` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `UITableView` like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CategoryRow
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CategoryRow(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    }
    else {
    }
    cell!.tag = indexPath.section
    cell?.collection.tag = (100 * indexPath.section) + 1
    cell?.collection.reloadData()
    cell?.collection.delegate = self
    return cell!
}
```

Then I get view by using tag method `viewWithTag` inside `scrollViewDidScroll` like

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    for var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ {
        let cell2 = self.view .viewWithTag((100 * i) + 1) as? UICollectionView

        if cell2 != nil {
            cell2!.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```