# I want to create the collectionView like it has in JIOtv App. This is something new, Answer not available on Internet

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, epg

I am attaching the image of JIOtv App. Please help me. I am looking for same EPG

[image]

Comment: I have refer many code and even tried it but still not able to design the collectionView like JIOtv App.

Comment: Have you check it? https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/assessment-view

Comment: yes Bilal, i saw this but when i try to put image on first column, it is not working. I have created separate collectionViewCell as well for image

Comment: What is the exact issue while adding image?

Comment: I want 25 column including the image of tv channel. It simply show the image and 3 columns, other columns in next row. so it shows row by row and not like the column.

Comment: I don't know how to add image here. Give me your email id. I will send you the screenshot of the app in simulator.

Comment: I have sent you email with the screenshot of my App

Comment: Bilal any solution of this problem?

Comment: Please upvote someone so it reach to maximum iOS app developer. This is something new and not available anywhere on Internet.

Comment: I am able to load the image in column and in remaining column channel content.

Comment: Now the challenge is to show the cell width dynamically as per the time duration of the channel. This is the main challenge. I am facing

Comment: I found the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996425/change-collection-view-cell-width-at-runtime

Comment: Same question asked in above link but Correct Answer is not given in above link as well.

Comment: I am looking for formula to calculate the width dynamically for each cell

Comment: That's too broad, and there are a few EPG code, but it's complex and might not do exactly what you want. But that's up to you to modify them...

Comment: @Larme thanks for the comments. yes I am trying to make the EPG like this.

Comment: Anybody knows how the EPG View gets updated while scrolling. I mean initially there is dummy data than data gets loaded and cell width gets set dynamically. Any Help is welcome.

Comment: @RaxitPandya Hi Man, I am working for the same to create EPG like TATA Sky and JioTV app. Did you completed it for your app ??

Comment: @RaxitPandya I want to set content offset for collectionview according to current time and program time.

Comment: @RaxitPandya can you slightly describe the current time line view implementation

Answer (score 0):

That is EPG data for tv you will never have one like but  [HERE](https://github.com/thejeraldo/EPG)